# Firestore transaction - reading data where document does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How could one do the following:

1) If a document exists, read it, and update the application token field.

2) If a document does not exist, set all fields with default values.

I am trying to achieve that with a Firestore transaction, but it's failing in the second case.

```
let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document((user?.uid)!)
       Firestore.firestore().runTransaction({ (transaction, errorPointer) -> Any? in
            let userDoc : DocumentSnapshot
            do {
                try userDoc = transaction.getDocument(ref)
            }
            catch _ as NSError {
                return nil
            }
       })
}
```

I am calling this method inside the firebaseLogin method I have. Basically, giving more context, if the user is creating his account (through Facebook, for instance), set default fields like name and email. If the user has already an account, update only applicationToken (for FCM).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't look like you've attempted #2 yet.  I don't see where any document is being updated.

Comment: It does not make sense to have an optional user class combined with a force unwrap and besides that firebase retrieve would fail if the user?.uid would return nil without the force unwrap

Comment: @DougStevenson, yes because I am not sure if I should handle the `catch _ as NSError` as the 'No account exists' possibility. What about if there's no internet connection? Wouldn't that throw the error the same way?